# Login page alignment issue on higher resolution

Tags: css

I have designed a login page which includes username textbox, password textbox, login button, remember me link & forgot password link but the last two links are not coming proper on higher resolution, how can I align it?

Comment: Please show us the problem, so we can see what is going on. Share the code, so we can fix it. Tell us what you have tried, so we want to help you. If you give us nothing, we will have nothing to help you with. There are clear instructions on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Read them, take your time and put some effort into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't done it yet, you can wrap the links in a div container and align it properly along with the rest of the form.

But I do agree it'd be easier if you showed us what exactly is going on on a smaller and on higher res. Have you tried different browser? Some of the rendering engines interpret certain elements differently and that might cause you troubles later on too.

Cheers!

Comment: Its coming same on all browsers, actually when I am zooming the screen, images goes down in two lines.